# Як сказати одним словом "друкарська помилка"?

Tags: одним-словом

Як одним словом назвати **друкарську помилку**, яка трапляється при помилковому наборі тексту на клавіатурі?

В російській є доволі усталене слово <sub>рос.</sub>*опечатка*.

[Тут](http://rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=17&t=5518) пишуть, що правильним варіантом є словосполучення *«друкарська помилка»*.
Або, тривіально, *«типографська помилка»*.

Пошук в інтернеті показує, що найчастіше використовується **«злодрук»**.

На мовознавчих форумах автори запропонували величезну кількість <s>неоковирних словесних покручів</s> продуктів самодіяльності, але особисто мені вони здаються або просто жахливими, або страшенно жахливими. :)
Серед них:

- *одрук, одруківка, обдруківка, хибодрук, хибнодрук, чортик* — [тут](http://ua-mova.livejournal.com/423583.html);
- *хибодрук, обпечатка, описка, блуд, друколяп* — [тут](http://ua-mova.livejournal.com/1270739.html);
- або тривіальні варіанти: *помилка, похибка, огріх, хиба*;

Ці слова, на мою думку, мають наступні недоліки (у різній комбінації):

- виглядає як канцеляризм і калька з російської: *одруківка*;
- скупчення приголосних: о**бдр**уківка, о**бп**ечатка, хи**бн**о**др**ук;
- невластива комбінація коренів: **хибо-** на початку слова;
- невластиве використання кореня "-печатка";
- загальна неточність, слово має велику кількість інших значень: *помилка, хиба*;

**Запитання:** чи існує одне слово, яке б не страждало на вищезазначені недоліки?

Comment: «Пошук в інтернеті показує, що найчастіше використовується „злодрук“.» — де Ви шукаєте? В гуглі: [одруківка](//www.google.com/search?q=%22одруківка%22&num=100&start=100) — 132, [одрук](//www.google.com/search?q=%22одрук%22&num=100&start=100) — 123, [обдруківка](//www.google.com/search?q=%22обдруківка%22&num=100&start=100) — 81, [хибодрук](//www.google.com/search?q=%22хибодрук%22&num=100&start=100) — 70, [хибнодрук](//www.google.com/search?q=%22хибнодрук%22&num=100&start=100) і [злодрук](//www.google.com/search?q=%22злодрук%22&num=100) — по 14 (найнижчі показники).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Одрук** і **друкарська помилка**. [Перший варіант](http://sum.in.ua/f/odruk) менш відомий, можна [користуватись](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA) обома.

Answer (score 8):

Я змінив свою думку (стару версію відповіді можна побачити [тут](/revisions/696/1)).

1. Є словникове і цілком уживане слово «**[опи́ска](http://sum.in.ua/s/opyska)**».

   Так, воно стосується акту письма, а не суто друкування. Але, як влучно зазначив один користувач Фейсбуку: «Письменник лишається письменником, навіть коли друкує». Поняття «писа́ти» в сучасному світі не обмежується лише безпосереднім рисуванням літер за допомогою ручки/крейди/тощо, а позначає будь-який процес візуального зображення літер (і навіть фіксування думки загалом), незалежно від способу. Адже ми кажемо, наприклад, «напиши Петру електронною поштою / Skype'ом / у Фейсбуці» — незважаючи на те, що це робиться зазвичай на клавіатурі. «Писа́ти» вже давно стало гіперонімом (словом із ширшим значенням) до слова «друкува́ти». (Навіть більше того: слово «друкува́ти» почало свій шлях із позначення масово-типографського способу відтворення інформації, потім поширилось на друкарські машинки, а з них — на комп'ютерні клавіатури і принтери, але я не впевнений, що ми зараз на клавіатурах друкуємо, а не пишемо/набираємо — мені особисто «надрукуй Петру <щось>» більше асоціюється із «роздрукуй його <щось> на своєму принтері», а не «набери клавіатурою і відправ Петру <щось>».)

   Отже на мою думку, цілком достатнім є слово «опи́ска». Нам рідко насправді потрібно вкладати в це слово саме спосіб письма: якщо ми робимо помилку при письмі від руки — то це описка, якщо ми помиляємося при наборі на клавіатурі — то це теж описка, якщо ми мовимо голосом і система розпізнавання голосу через нашу обмовку або власну ваду неправильно трансформує його в письмовий текст — то це теж описка.

   - Якщо вже вкрай важливо позначити саме спосіб письма, то тоді я, [як і Nazar Tokar](/a/687), схиляюся до слова «**о́друк**». Хоч це слово, наскільки я знаю, в словниках і не зафіксоване (окрім так званих народних/відкритих), але воно доволі широко вживається (наприклад, [Вікіпедія](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA)) і при цьому, на мій особистий погляд, звучить краще за явні кальки «одруківка» і «обдруківка».
2. Існує словосполучення «друка́рський чо́ртик». Його хоч раз вжила [дюжина періодичних чи неперіодичних видань різних років](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D1%87%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%22+OR+%22%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D1%87%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%22+OR+%22%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83+%D1%87%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83%22+OR+%22%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83+%D1%87%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%22+OR+%22%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC+%D1%87%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%22) (здебільшого західноукраїнських і емігрантських); також [на форумі СЛОВНИКа.ua](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/index.php?showtopic=35&pid=237#entry237) користувач Pere незалежно від мене вжитки показує. Іноді одне зі слів чи обидва беруть у лапки.

   Дехто наполягає на можливості вживання «**чо́ртик**» і без епітету «друка́рський». Я особисто таких ужитків не зустрічав, але, наприклад, С. Караванський в «Російсько-українському словнику складної лексики» (1998, Київ, «Академія», 712 с, ISBN 966-580-032-9) пише:

   > опеча́тка: <sub>[з ]ж[ивої ]м[ови]</sub> чо́ртик

Comment: До речі, я вважаю, що коли «змінив думку», має сенс залишити стару відповідь і написати другу, нову. Таким чином зберігаються голоси, і видно, яку з версій підтримує спільнота. А робити натомість drastic changes своїм відповідям псує усю картину і провокує до unupvotes тих, кому подобався «старий» варіант і не подобається «новий».

Comment: @bytebuster, я над цим думав. Теж схилявся до того, що Ви кажете. Але побачив [оце](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268300).

Comment: Так, слушний аргумент, але там змінився фактичний матеріал. А особисте ставлення не скасувало того, що є варіант «злодрук», який просто перестав подобатися одному користувачеві — але не зник же зовсім. :)

Comment: @bytebuster, оу, я просто хибне посилання дав.

Answer (score 3):

Серед умов було зазначено:

> Ці слова, на мою думку, мають наступні недоліки (у різній комбінації):
>   <...>
>   * загальна неточність, слово має велику кількість інших значень: *помилка*, *хиба*

Щодо *помилки* ми з паном Олександром у [сусідній відповіді](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/723/36) подискутували. А я потім подумав, чи буде *хиба* так само двозначно трактуватися в контексті?

Принагідно згадаємо, що *друкарська помилка* історично була помилкою [*складача*](http://sum.in.ua/s/skladach). Наразі вона асоціюється лише з помилкою при наборі тексту на клавіатурі. Хоча ми і друкуємо тексти, але не є [*друкарями*](http://sum.in.ua/s/drukar) (у своїй більшості).

Якщо ж розглядати лише сучасний процес, то така помилка виникає тоді, коли палець не потрапляє на потрібну клавішу, тобто [*хибить*](http://sum.in.ua/s/skhybyty) мимо цілі. Власне [*хиба*](http://sum.in.ua/s/khyba) в тому числі означає *помилку*. Інші значення, на мою думку, не можуть бути двоїсто трактовані:

> Я у вас хибу знайшов.
>   Ви тут схибили.

Окрім того, *схибили* на 5 позицій коротше за *одрукувалися* і на 6 позицій за *зробили одрук*. *Хиба* на 1 позицію коротше за *одрук*. Коротші варіянти мають тенденцію краще приживатися.

---

Якщо дозволено словотвір, можна утворити *схибу*, що буде окремо від *хиби*.

Також можна відштовхнутися від неповороткості пальців (*fat finger*) і повернути на цей світ одне із позабутих слів, наприклад, [*товба*](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B1%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on).

Answer (score 1):

На мою думку, слід просто використовувати слово **помилка** і не акцентувати без потреби, що вона "**друкарська**".
Ми ж не кажемо, що учень зробив "письмову помилку", чи футболіст допустив "футбольну помилку", чи шахіст зробив "шахову помилку".

Comment: Тоді виникатиме двояке читання. "*Ой, я помилився!*" — це про **суть** надрукованого чи просто літера пропущена?

Comment: @Nash Bridges: як правило, з контексту зрозуміло про яку помилку йде мова. А що ви розумієте під "суттю надрукованого"? Адже, якщо ненавмисно пропущена літера,  слово, рядок чи сторінка - це все "друкарська помилка". А якщо друкар свідомо змінює текст (його сутність) - це вже буде не помилка, а зовсім інше поняття залежно від мети вчинку (редагування, перекручення, шкідництво...)

Comment: @OlexandrMatviienko, відповім за Nash Bridges: це може мати значення, коли автор думки і друкар — одна й та сама людина. Тоді помилки цієї людини можуть розділятися на два види: помилки як автора (коли автор неправильно щось думав, а потім визнає це) й помилки як друкаря (коли через якісь причини зафіксоване не відповідає подумки сформульованому). Update: бачу, що Nash Bridges таки відповідав, просто коментарі були потім вилучені.